# making a onClick radio buttons to show an image

Tags: function, radio-button, getelementbyid

need help with this, trying to make the flags images open when i click on them and not show till they are clicked on. i'll mess with the sizing and everything else after i try fix this problem first, but would like to say thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<head>

<title>Flags</title>

</head>

<body>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

    function check_value(fieldvalue)
    {    
        switch(fieldvalue)
        {
            case 1:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='argentina.jpg'>";
                    break;

            case 2:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='australia.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 3:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='bolivia.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 4:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='cuba.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 5:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='finland.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 6:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='france.jpg'>";
                    break;

            case 7:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='italy.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 8:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='peru.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 9:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='syria.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

            case 10:

                document.getElementById("flags").innerHTML = "<img src='tunisia.jpg'>"; 
                    break;

        }
    }

</script>

<form name='flag1'>
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="argentina" >Argentina</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="australia" >Australia</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="bolivia" >Bolivia</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="cuba" >Cuba</td>  
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="finland" >Finland</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="france" >France</td> 
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="italy" >Italy</td>  
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="peru" >Peru</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="syria" >Syria</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="tunisia" >Tunisia</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img src="argentina.jpg" onclick='check_value(1)' ></td>
<td><img src="australia.jpg" onclick='check_value(2)' ></td>
<td><img src="bolivia.jpg" onclick='check_value(3)' ></td>
<td><img src="cuba.jpg" onclick='check_value(4)' ></td>
<td><img src="finland.jpg" onclick='check_value(5)' ></td>
<td><img src="france.jpg" onclick='check_value(6)' ></td>
<td><img src="italy.jpg" onclick='check_value(7)' ></td>
<td><img src="peru.jpg" onclick='check_value(8)' ></td>
<td><img src="syria.jpg" onclick='check_value(9)' ></td>
<td><img src="tunisia.jpg" onclick='check_value(10)' ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id='flags'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me. What isn't working for you?

Comment: the pictures shows when i open the html file and i need the pictures to only show when i clicked on them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as I understand it, you only want to display the flag images when you click on the *actual radio buttons*. You have two problems:

First, each of the table cells will display the images as soon as the page loads:

```
<td><img src="argentina.jpg" onclick='check_value(1)' ></td>
<td><img src="australia.jpg" onclick='check_value(2)' ></td>
(etc)
```

Second, you're adding the onclick functions to those `img` tags. That means those functions will be called only when you click on those images (which you don't even want to display), not the radio buttons.

To 'fix' this, first delete this entire block of code:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="argentina.jpg" onclick='check_value(1)' ></td>
<td><img src="australia.jpg" onclick='check_value(2)' ></td>
<td><img src="bolivia.jpg" onclick='check_value(3)' ></td>
<td><img src="cuba.jpg" onclick='check_value(4)' ></td>
<td><img src="finland.jpg" onclick='check_value(5)' ></td>
<td><img src="france.jpg" onclick='check_value(6)' ></td>
<td><img src="italy.jpg" onclick='check_value(7)' ></td>
<td><img src="peru.jpg" onclick='check_value(8)' ></td>
<td><img src="syria.jpg" onclick='check_value(9)' ></td>
<td><img src="tunisia.jpg" onclick='check_value(10)' ></td>
</tr>
```

Second, add the `onclick` functions to each of your radio controls, like this:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="flags2" value="argentina" onclick='check_value(1)' >Argentina</td>
```

Personally, I would do this with a single function, using the country name as input.